# iOS XMPP How to display all users in single section in tableview

Tags: ios, xmpp

I Have fetched XMPP users using NSFetchResultController but it is displaying online users in one section and offline users in another section, I want to display all users in a single section, i'm unable to combine all users together. How to display in single tableview section.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
 return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
 {
     NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

     if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
     {
         id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = sections[sectionIndex];

         int section = [sectionInfo.name intValue];
         switch (section)
         {
             case 0  : return @"Available";
             case 1  : return @"Away";
             default : return @"Offline";
         }
     }

     return @"";
 }


 - (void)configurePhotoForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell user:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)user
 {
 if (user.photo != nil)
 {
 cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
 }
 else
 {
 NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

 if (photoData != nil)
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
 else
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];
 }
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
        NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

        if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
        {
            id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = sections[sectionIndex];
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
        }

        return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell =(UITableViewCell *)[self.usersTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"users"];
    UILabel *nameLabel =(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    nameLabel.text = user.displayName;
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create fetchedResultsController? It is responsible for dividing fetched entities by sections. So you can simply create it in following way:

```
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil // pass nil here if you want single section
                                cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Will you please help me what i have to return for numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTable. .

Comment: I little confused but it worked like charm you saved my day  Thank you . . .

Comment: In your code it returns number of sections of `fetchedResultsController `. But since now section only one due to change in `fetchedResultsController ` initialization, it returns 1 section. That's why no change in `fetchedResultsController ` required.